# How to transfer photos not in Camera Roll from iPhone to PC?

Tags: iphone, photos, data-transfer

I upgraded my iPhone and now the photos are in a folder `Second images` (no reel) and when I try to view them on the PC they are not shown. On the iPhone it only gives me the option to send them by mail (and there are 600 photos), so it's not a viable option.

Can anyone tell me how the transfer the images to my PC?

Answer (score 1):

**Import photos in Windows 8**

Import photos and video from your device to your PC:

1. Connect your iOS device to your computer.
2. Move the cursor to the upper-right corner and click the magnifying glass icon.
3. Type Computer and press Return.
4. Right-click the logo for your device and
   click "Import pictures and videos."
5. Click More Options.
6. Click the Browse button next to the "Import images to" field and choose where
   to import your Camera Roll's photos. By default, these will import
   to the My Pictures folder.
7. Select "Delete files from device after
   importing."

   - If you delete photos after you import them, you can
     reduce the size of your Camera Roll and improve backup and restore
     times.
   - If you wish to import the photos to other computers, don't
     select this option.
   - If you don't want Windows to delete photos from
     your camera on subsequent imports, deselect this option when you're
     finished.
8. After setting your import options, click OK to dismiss the
   window.
9. Click Import.
10. After the import is complete, Windows will
    display your photos.

Just >>> [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4083) <<<

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just want to sync few photos from iPhone to PC, using USB cable is a little troublesome in this situation. Many people prefer to store photos in iCloud Photo Library to share or transfer. iCloud is a good photo transfer app for users to access photos and videos among several devices. You can download photos whenever you need.

1. Log on your iCloud account both on your iPhone and PC.
2. Pick images you want to transfer and click “Photos”.
3. Click Options and then enable iCloud Photo Library.
4. Choose “Done” after all operations, next click “Apply”.
5. Open a file Explorer Window on PC, click “iCloud Photos”.
6. Choose Photos you want to transfer from iPhone to PC and click “Download”.

Be sure that you have connected Wi-Fi, or you will fail to transfer photos from iPhone to PC. You can also sync images with iCloud Photo Stream, but you can store photos for only 30 days there. Choose one you like and start importing photos and videos with iCloud.